# Adding skin variables to Blogger template

Tags: blogger, blogger-templates

I'm creating a Blogger template. I have an external CSS file that handles the bulk of the styling.

However, I want to be able to color my blog post titles easily through Blogger's Template Designer. So I added the following snippet to my Blogger template. But it doesn't work.

**How can I add a variable to my theme that can be customized in Blogger's Template Designer?**

```
<b:skin>
<![CDATA[

/*
<Variable name="posttitlecolor" description="Post Title Color" type="color" default="#000000"/>
*/

.post-title {
    color: $(posttitlecolor);
}

]]>
</b:skin>
```

Over four hours of research, trial, and error has produced no results, so I would be extremely grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem with Blogger.  I signed up for a new account, used the exact same template, and it worked.